# Combine several data with their parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-sql

Suggestions of how to formulate this question better are welcome.
Let's say I have a database query like the following:

```
var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
var db = openDatabase("Oscommerce", "1.0", "Oscommerce Database", dbSize);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM customers_basket WHERE customers_id="1"', [], function(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length,
            i;

        var products_options_array = {};
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            var r = results.rows.item(i);
            products_options_array[r.customers_basket_id] = r;
            console.log(products_options_array);
        }

    });
});
```

Below I provide an HTML output example.
All attributes inside the `div`s are the database fields with their corresponding values.

The answers I got from jacob and Gaby were based on the HTML below. This was my mistake, because I thought it would be easier to understand my problem if I provided it like that.

```
<div customers_basket_attributes_id="1" customers_id="1" products_id="1{4}2{3}6" 
     products_options_id="4"  products_options_value_id="2">product 1</div>
<div customers_basket_attributes_id="2" customers_id="1" products_id="1{4}2{3}6" 
     products_options_id="3"  products_options_value_id="6">product 1</div> 

<div customers_basket_attributes_id="3" customers_id="1" products_id="1{4}3{3}5" 
     products_options_id="4"  products_options_value_id="3">product 1</div> 
<div customers_basket_attributes_id="4" customers_id="1" products_id="1{4}3{3}5" 
     products_options_id="3"  products_options_value_id="5">product 1</div>

<div customers_basket_attributes_id="3" customers_id="1" products_id="2{4}3{3}5" 
     products_options_id="4"  products_options_value_id="3">product 2</div> 
<div customers_basket_attributes_id="4" customers_id="1" products_id="2{4}3{3}5" 
     products_options_id="3"  products_options_value_id="5">product 2</div>
```

How can I get it like this:

```
<div products_id="1{4}2{3}6">
<p>product1</p>
<p>products_options_id_4 : products_options_value_id_2</p>
<p>products_options_id_3 : products_options_value_id_6</p>
</div>

<div products_id="1{4}3{3}5">
<p>product1</p>
<p>products_options_id_4 : products_options_value_id_3</p>
<p>products_options_id_3 : products_options_value_id_5</p>
</div>

<div products_id="2{4}3{3}5">
<p>product2</p>
<p>products_options_id_4 : products_options_value_id_3</p>
<p>products_options_id_3 : products_options_value_id_5</p>
</div>
```

And for more GUI, it should look at the end like [this `JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/whitehat/nvhQx/).

**SOLVED WITH JACOB'S EXAMPLE:**

```
var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
var db = openDatabase("Oscommerce", "1.0", "Oscommerce Database", dbSize);
var data = {};
var cart_str = '';
var products_options_array = {};
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM customers_basket WHERE customers_id="1"', [], function(tx, results) {

         var len = results.rows.length,i;


        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            var r = results.rows.item(i);
            products_options_array[r.customers_basket_id] = r;
            //console.log(products_options_array);
        }
        for (key in products_options_array) {
            var value = products_options_array[key];
            customers_basket_id = value['customers_basket_id'];
            customers_id = value['customers_id'];
            products_id = value['products_id'];
            products_options_id = value['products_options_id'];
            products_options_txt = value['products_options_txt'];
            products_options_value_id = value['products_options_value_id'];
            products_options_value_txt = value['products_options_value_txt'];
            customers_basket_quantity = value['customers_basket_quantity'];
            final_price = value['final_price'];
            customers_basket_date_added = value['customers_basket_date_added'];

            cart_str += '<div customers_basket_attributes_id="' + customers_basket_id + '" customers_id="' + customers_id + '" products_id="' + products_id + '" products_options_id="' + products_options_id + '"  products_options_value_id="' + products_options_value_id + '" style="display:none">' + products_id + '</div>';

        }

         $('#input').html(cart_str);


        $('#input div').each(function() {
            var div = $(this);
            var productId = div.attr('products_id');
            var optionId = div.attr('products_options_id');

            if (!(productId in data)) data[productId] = {
                name: div.text(),
                options: {}
            };
            if (!(optionId in data[productId].options)) {
                var optionValueId = div.attr('products_options_value_id');
                data[productId].options[optionId] = optionValueId;
            }
        });

        $.each(data, function(productId, product) {

            var productDiv = $('<div/>').attr('products_id', productId).appendTo('#output');
            $('<p/>').text(product.name).appendTo(productDiv);

            $.each(product.options, function(optionId, optionValueId) {
                $('<p/>').text('products_options_id_' + optionId + ' : products_options_value_id_' + optionValueId).appendTo(productDiv);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Where did `customers_basket_attributes_id` and `customers_id` go? Do you want to drop them?

Comment: in the output they arent need, i thought i provide the data i have to generate an output.

Comment: Excuse me if this is a stupid question but do you only have "product 1" in your sample? If you should have different products, it would be helpful to name them appropriately to better understand your question.

Comment: I am assuming the missing `=` are there, in the working code, right ?

Comment: Both request are edited for you/for me

Comment: I think you'll just have to read in the elements and their attributes, delete them from the DOM and then build the new version up from scratch.

Comment: All data is actualy called from a webdb, i thought it would be easyer to understand my problem if i show the dynamic outputted data into a simple html code.what you see above is actualy my db structure

Comment: @wHiTeHaT, how are you building the original output ? It might be wiser to build the desired output directly from the db data, instead of using client-side script.. so a server-side language is more appropriate..

Comment: See my answer for doing this solely with jQuery.  If you have the source data server-side, it would be better to output the desired content directly instead.

Comment: Yes @Jacob i just figured that out,now i should try in practice.In perspective view of the code it should be easy.However.... yeah well..i'm not so professional,will probaly take me day's if not weeks lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this up into three steps:

1. Iterate through the source document.
2. Build a representative data structure.
3. Build the output document.

The resulting data structure in step #2 should look something like this:

```
{
    '1{4}2{3}6': {
        name: 'product1',
        options: {
            '4': '2',
            '3': '6'
        }
    },
    '1{4}3{3}5': {
        name: 'product1',
        options: {
            '4': '3',
            '3': '5'
        }
    },
    '2{4}3{3}5': {
        name: 'product1',
        options: {
            '4': '3',
            '3': '5'
        }
    }
}
```

To build the structure, try something like this with jQuery:

```
var data = {};
$('#input div').each(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    var productId = div.attr('products_id');
    var optionId = div.attr('products_options_id');     

    if (!(productId in data))
        data[productId] = { name: div.text(), options: {} };
    if (!(optionId in data[productId].options)) {
        var optionValueId = div.attr('products_options_value_id');
        data[productId].options[optionId] = optionValueId;
    }
});
```

Then, to build the output content, do this:

```
$.each(data, function(productId, product) {

    var productDiv = $('<div/>').attr('products_id', productId).appendTo('#output');
    $('<p/>').text(product.name).appendTo(productDiv);

    $.each(product.options, function(optionId, optionValueId) {
        $('<p/>')
            .text(
                'products_options_id_' + optionId 
                + ' : products_options_value_id_' + optionValueId)
            .appendTo(productDiv);
    });
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7UEA/1/) showing the result.

Comment: Your fiddle seems verry well for adapting to use the output that is retrieved from the webDB.

Comment: I hope you find a good job in the near future that fullfill al your wishes what a job should contain for you

Answer (score 1):

This works for the example. I hope it is clear enough so you can adapt it to real data..

```
var uniqueIdList = {}; // this will hold the unique product_id's
// find all divs with products_id attribute and store that id
var products = $('div[products_id]').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('products_id');
    if (uniqueIdList[id] === undefined){
        uniqueIdList[id] = true;
    }
});
for (var uId in uniqueIdList ){ // for each product_id
    var div = $('<div>', {id: uId}).appendTo('body'); // create a new div (container) and assign the id
    products.filter('[products_id="'+uId+'"]').each(function(idx){ // find all divs that have the same product_id
        var self = $(this);
        var option = self.attr('products_options_id'),
            value = self.attr('products_options_value_id'); // extract the info

        if (idx === 0) { // for the first of each group extract the text (assuming it is the same for all of same group)
            $('<p>',{text: self.text()}).appendTo(div); // ad text to div (as a p tag)
        }
        $('<p>',{text: option  + ' : ' + value}).appendTo(div); // add info to the div
    })
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dRFCh/1/

Comment: omg , i just knocked myself out becouse i was so stupid to give a output example as a html output,however i need to find me a way to use your example from my output of the dB.I'm realy sorry abouth this couse you did a greath job.

Comment: @wHiTeHaT, yeah .. i figured so after reading you comment in the question, but it was too late :) no worries.. so what back-end language do you use ? and what DB platform ?

Comment: i use webDB,works as sqlite,most mysql statements working.so al the data i took as output are database variables.i'm sort of on the last stage of my "hobby project",reading the data out of the shoppingcart.

Comment: the database is on the client side (localstorage),that is what webDB do,simular to indexDB.An example of what i accomplished so far: http://www.osc2nuke.com/rot/ works on safari-chrome and iphone/android